# disable ssl on specific page directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have small problem with my site. I want use SSL on everything subpages, without path **primary folder / generate** In primary folder is installed wordpress.

Yui API use http:// protocol so SSL blocked my scripts. How can i do this?

I wrote this rule in .htaccess and paste this to generate folder, but doesn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/generate
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/generate
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the following rules in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(generate)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(generate)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

***What does the above do?***

What this does is first check if HTTPs is on or off. If it is off then it will forward everything to HTTPs except for the directory `generate`. If HTTPs is already on then the second rule checks to make sure `generate` is on HTTP, if not then it will redirect `generate` back to HTTP.

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/generate
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/generate
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, but instead of turning off SSL in this directory, it stops loading me the whole page. What could be the reason?

Comment: The above code does not do that... strange. Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` and did you clear your cache?

Comment: It is full .htaccess file for my website: https://pastebin.com/mKkq1nVR Yup, i clear my browser cache at least five times

Comment: First thing I notice is you have two lots of the same code, at the top and at the bottom, not sure why you have that...? Where are you placing the new code? Try placing it at the top and then test it.

Comment: Have i to put  this code between <ifmodule></ifmodule>?

Comment: No, just put in as is.

Comment: Website works, but SSL still is active in /generate. I pasted it on top

Comment: Can I make a cloudflare rule bypassing this subpage, is there such a possibility?

Comment: You could try, but tbh I'm not sure how to do that. The code above should stop `generate` from being HTTPs... what is the full URL/path for that directory?

Comment: domains/mydomain.com/public_html/generate/

Comment: Please see my edit. I've made small changes to the code you had before. Please try that :)

Comment: Nope - your code disabled SSL in mypage.com nope in mypage.com/generate I don't know what is the cause, but i create new page rule on cloudflare https://mypage/generate/* and SSL is disabled, but i get information and too many connections and the site does not load

Comment: The code wouldn't disable SSL. It must be clashing with something then.