# Letsencrypt apache, disable https for specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lets-encrypt

Im using ubuntu, apache and letsencrypt. I want to disable https for one directory.

This is my .htaccess right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#HTTP TO HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

domain.nl should redirect to https://domain.nl. (As it does now)
http://domain.nl/keuken (or http://domain.nl/keuken/keuken.php is also ok) should just be http.

I can not get it to work.

I tried several solutions from stackoverflow but either it does nothing or i get to many redirects.

Comment: What have you tried? The directive above is not a "HTTP TO HTTPS" redirect, despite what the comment suggests. Is it possible you have another redirect later in your application?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I commented out everything in my .htaccess and everything is still redirected to https. So i guess the redirects are made via a virtualhost file?

I tried things like this in my .htaccess:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/keuken/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
--------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/keuken/keuken.php$
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [last,redirect=301]
---------------------------------
But that does not work.

Comment: Please edit your question with your code attempts. Unformatted code in comments (apart from being hard to read) can miss special characters (due to the markdown formatting) making the code invalid. Also bear in mind that 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser, so can make testing problematic. Test with 302s to avoid caching issues and clear all caches before testing.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please try searching before posting a new question, there are many answers to this question here already, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539114/remove-ssl-integration-from-a-specific-folder-using-htaccess, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898890/how-to-disable-https-redirect-on-a-single-page-with-htaccess, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631336/disable-ssl-on-specific-page-directory ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove SSL integration from a specific folder using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539114/remove-ssl-integration-from-a-specific-folder-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The .htaccess in my question has nothing to do with it.
I changed the virtualhost config file: 000-default.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/keuken(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If i am correct this means everything except /keuken is redirected to https.

Comment: "everything except /keuken" - Any URL that _starts_ `/keuken` (the trailing `/?` is redundant), including `/keukenanything`. You perhaps want `!^/keuken(/|$)` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the .htaccess solution was not working? Shouldn't the .htaccess override the default config? Things like + or - Indexes do work.

Comment: Rules directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container are processed _early_ (before `.htaccess`). mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess` would only "override" directives in a corresponding `<Directory>` container (inside the `<VirtualHost>`).